# Building a string with chars

Tags: c++, string, io, append

I've written a sort of stream class that read a FASTA file sequence by sequence:

Interface:

```
class Sequence_stream{
    public:
        Sequence_stream(const char* Filename, std::string Format); // Constructor.
        NucleotideSequence get();    // Get a sequence from file.
    private:
        std::string FileName;
        std::ifstream FileStream;
        std::string FileFormat;
};
```

Implementation:

```
Sequence_stream::Sequence_stream(const char* Filename, std::string Format)
{
    FileName = Filename;
    FileStream.open(FileName);
    FileFormat = Format;
    std::cout << "Filestream is open: " << FileStream.is_open() << std::endl;
}

NucleotideSequence Sequence_stream::get()
{
    if(FileFormat=="fasta")
    {
        if (FileStream.is_open())
        {
            char currentchar;
            std::string name;
            std::vector<Nucleotide> sequence;
            currentchar = FileStream.get();
            if (currentchar == '>') {  // Check that the start of the first line is the fasta head character.
                currentchar = FileStream.get(); // Proceed to get the full name of the sequence. Get characters until the newline character.
                while(currentchar != '\n')
                {
                    name.append(currentchar);
                    currentchar = FileStream.get();
                } // done getting names, now let's get the sequence.
                currentchar = FileStream.get();
                while(currentchar != '>')
                {
                    if(currentchar != '\n'){
                        sequence.push_back(Nucleotide(currentchar));
                    }
                    currentchar = FileStream.get();
                }
                if(currentchar == '>')
                {
                    FileStream.unget();
                }
                return NucleotideSequence(name, sequence);
            } else {
                std::cout << "The first line of the file was not a fasta format description line beginning with '>'. Are you sure the file is of FASTA format?" << std::endl;
                return;
            }

        } else {
            std::cout << "The filestream is not open" << endl;
        }
        return NucleotideSequence(name, sequence);
    }
}
```

I'm having issues with the get method, I'm trying to read in a sequence character by character and add it to a string called name with append, but when I compile it complains it's not a constant character:

/local/yrq12edu/Dropbox/libHybRIDS/HybRIDS_Sequences.cpp|75|error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

However the variable currentchar can't be a constant since it changes during the loops when new characters are fetched - how would be the best way to do this? I've thought of making current char a const char* instead of char but then I get a load of read only errors when I try to deference it it get the character value in the code:

```
NucleotideSequence Sequence_stream::get()
{
    if(FileFormat=="fasta")
    {
        if (FileStream.is_open())
        {
            const char* currentchar;
            std::string name;
            std::vector<Nucleotide> sequence;
            *currentchar = FileStream.get();
            if (*currentchar == '>') {  // Check that the start of the first line is the fasta head character.
                *currentchar = FileStream.get(); // Proceed to get the full name of the sequence. Get characters until the newline character.
                while(*currentchar != '\n')
                {
                    name.append(currentchar);
                    *currentchar = FileStream.get();
                } // done getting names, now let's get the sequence.
                *currentchar = FileStream.get();
                while(*currentchar != '>')
                {
                    if(*currentchar != '\n'){
                        sequence.push_back(Nucleotide(*currentchar));
                    }
                    *currentchar = FileStream.get();
                }
                if(*currentchar == '>')
                {
                    FileStream.unget();
                }
                return NucleotideSequence(name, sequence);
            } else {
                std::cout << "The first line of the file was not a fasta format description line beginning with '>'. Are you sure the file is of FASTA format?" << std::endl;
                return;
            }

        } else {
            std::cout << "The filestream is not open" << endl;
        }
        return NucleotideSequence(name, sequence);
    }
}
```

How should I go about this? I've thought maybe assigning the value of currentchar to a temporary constant and then feeding that into append?

Thanks,
Ben.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
name.append(&currentchar,1);
```

instead of this:

```
name.append(currentchar);
```

The append method wants a pointer to a character.

Comment: That will try to interpret a single character as a null-terminated string, which will be disastrous.

Answer (score 0):

To append a single character to a string, the options are

```
name.append(1, currentchar);
name.push_back(currentchar);
name += currentchar;
```